# Deleted Fields PDOException Error

Tags: entities

I removed some fields from phpmyadmin; now I get the following error from Drupal:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'restech1_newDrupal.field_data_field_contactus_images' doesn't exist

I removed the contactus_images field together other fields I wasn't using, in order to make space on my server.

How do I get the site to come back?

Comment: Restore from backup, that's the safest thing to do. Any more manual 'intervention' could mess things up even worse

Comment: isnt there a way to just remove the instance of that field? i'm sure more issues will come as soon as i start on those pages as well. . . .

Comment: The only way is remove those fields from Drupal, since other modules could have data about them in their own tables. Removing something from the database directly is never a good idea.

Comment: i understand (now) that its a bad idea. but is there a way to remove these manually now?